# MYSQL import syntax error 1064 on digitalocean vps

Tags: sql, mysql

I've exported my wordpress sql database from my old host. I'm then trying to import it to my new VPS - the file is on the server and i run:

```
mysql -h localhost -u username -p wpdatabase < wpdatabase.sql.gz
```

I then get this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server versions for the right syntax to use near '? (there is actually like a down arrow symbol between the quote and the question mark.

I've been at this for hours. I'm totally lost, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me due to a validation of the version of mysql that does not let insert field or table with less than 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Login to mysql then
type

```
USE database_name;
```

then

```
source path/wpdatabase.sql
```

Comment: I got a load of errors doing this, is there any easy way to copy them all out so i can paste them here?

Comment: use `mysqlimport` if you have problems with source. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html